# SQL: how to pick a value based on other column in an aggregated column

Tags: mysql, group-by, conditional-statements, aggregate

If I have a table like this:

| team_id | score | timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 8 | 2022-01-05 |
| 1 | 10 | 2022-02-01 |
| 2 | 5 | 2022-01-06 |
| 2 | 9 | 2022-01-15 |
| 2 | 7 | 2022-01-20 |

and I only want the team ID and the latest score grouped by the ID:

| team_id | score |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 |
| 2 | 7 |

So the questions is when I group by the ID, how do I select the right score based on the timestamp? can I do this in one query? thanks.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/last-value-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Please [TAG](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms) your RDBMS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `max` window function:

```
select team_id, score from
(select *, max(timestamp) over(partition by team_id) as maxt from table_name) t
where timestamp = maxt;
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=998756cca1437ee7008cda4be9a0efe6)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT a.* FROM scores as a 
LEFT JOIN scores as b ON (a.teamid = b.teamid AND a.tmstamp < b.tmstamp)
WHERE b.tmstamp is NULL;
```

Essentially you join the table to itself based upon the team id but ensuring that the timestamp is the greater